# C++ How do you create a map that takes in a string and returns a func

Tags: c++, function, dictionary, func

I was wondering if there was a way that I could make a map(in C++) return a func. This is my code now and it doesn't work, I get a compiler error.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

map<string, void()> commands;

void method()
{
    cout << "IT WORKED!";
}

void Program::Run()
{
    commands["a"]();
}

Program::Program()
{
    commands["a"] = method;
    Run();
}
```

Any bit of advice would be awesome! Thank you in advance.

Comment: With C++11, `std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't store a function in a map -- only a pointer to a function. With a few other minor details cleaned up, you get something like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::map<std::string, void(*)()> commands;

void method() {
    std::cout << "IT WORKED!";
}

void Run() {
    commands["a"]();
}

int main(){ 
    commands["a"] = method;
    Run();
}
```

At least with g++ 4.7.1, this prints `IT WORKED!`, as you apparently wanted/expected.

Answer (score 2):

Again `typedef` is your friend.

```
typedef void (*func)();
map<string, func> commands;
```